# How do I compile C++ with Clang?

Tags: c++, clang

I have installed [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) by using apt-get in Ubuntu, and I can successfully compile C files using it. However, I have no idea how to compile C++ through it. What do I need to do to compile C++?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The command `clang` is for C, and the command `clang++` is for C++.

Answer (score 111):

I do not know why there is no answer directly addressing the problem. When you want to compile C++ program, it is best to use `clang++`, instead of using `clang`. For example, the following works for me:

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 test.cc -o test
```

If compiled correctly, it will produce the executable file `test`, and you can run the file by using `./test`.

Or you can just use `clang++ test.cc` to compile the program. It will produce a default executable file named [`a.out`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218262/6064933). Use `./a.out` to run the file.

The whole process is a lot like g++ if you are familiar with g++. See [this
post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24904101/6064933) to check which warnings are included with `-Wall` option. [This
page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#introduction) shows a list of diagnostic flags supported by Clang.

**A note on using `clang -x c++`**: Kim Gräsman says that you can also use
`clang -x c++` to compile CPP programs, but that may not be always viable. For example, I am having a simple program below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    /* std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; */
    std::vector<int> v(10, 5);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        sum += v[i]*2;
    }
    std::cout << "sum is " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`clang++ test.cc -o test` will compile successfully, but `clang -x c++` will
not, showing a lot of undefined reference errors. So I guess they are not exactly equivalent. It is best to use `clang++` instead of `clang -x c++` when compiling c++ programs to avoid extra troubles.

- clang version: 11.0.0
- Platform: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question.

Comment: @jdhao Thanks for the detailed answer. But there is one thing I do not understand. You said "When you want to compile C++ program, it is best to use clang++". Why using `g++` is not recommended?

Comment: @Mr.Robot I mean it is best to use `clang++` for compiling cpp, compared to using `clang`, not compared to using `g++`.

Comment: What about on Windows?

Comment: @Andrew I do not use clang on Windows. So I am not sure. If you use clang on Windows, it is easy to verify.

Answer (score 58):

Also, for posterity -- Clang (like GCC) accepts the `-x` switch to set the language of the input files, for example,

```
$ clang -x c++ some_random_file.txt
```

This mailing list thread explains the difference between `clang` and `clang++` well: *[Difference between clang and clang++](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Difference-between-clang-and-clang-td3001279.html)*

Comment: I had an linker error with _clang -x c++_ when compiled cpp file with `#include <iostream>`. _-lstdc++_ flag solved this problem.

Comment: I have the source code of Clang in front of my eyes now. During build (on Windows), it first builds `clang.exe`, and then copies that executable into `clang++.exe`. So it's the same executable, just at runtime it checks its own name to distinguish whether to behave as C or C++ compiler. HTH.

Comment: As a note, the option `-x c++` was very useful to give as an `-extra-arg` to *clang-tidy*, to force it to treat a .h file as containing C++ instead of C.

Comment: This is too limiting to be actually useful unless you build entire thing from source.

It's better to just use `clang++` and let it detect what kind of files you supply to it. When a project can contain `.cpp` files, `.ll` files (llvm ir) and `.o`, `.a`, `.so` and what not files from third party libraries, `clang -x c++` will just throw up.

Comment: I am also seeing the same issue as @Slav. For a very simple program, `clang++` works, but `clang -x c++` shows a lot of undefined reference errors (the other flags are the same). So I guess it is best to use `clang++`. Tested clang version: 11.0.0.

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1:

```
  clang++ your.cpp
```

Solution 2:

```
  clang your.cpp -lstdc++
```

Solution 3:

```
   clang -x c++ your.cpp
```

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar problem when building Clang from source (but not with `sudo apt-get install`. This might depend on the version of Ubuntu which you're running).

It might be worth checking if `clang++` can find the correct locations of your C++ libraries:

Compare the results of `g++ -v <filename.cpp>` and `clang++ -v <filename.cpp>`, under "#include < ... > search starts here:".

Answer (score 4):

Open a Terminal window and navigate to your project directory. Run these sets of commands, depending on which compiler you have installed:

**To compile multiple C++ files using clang++:**

```sh
$ clang++ *.cpp 
$ ./a.out
```

**To compile multiple C++ files using g++:**

```sh
$ g++ -c *.cpp 
$ g++ -o temp.exe *.o
$ ./temp.exe
```