# What does `-Wextra` flag mean in clang compiler?

Tags: c, clang

What is the meaning of `-Wextra` in *clang* compiler flag?

I was curious what does all the flags such as `-Wall`, `-Werror` means. I was able to find answers for others, but not `-Wextra`.

```
clang -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Comment: `-Wall` enables all warnings, except not actually all of them. The rest are in `-Wextra`, except not all of the rest. We have `-Weverything`, too, for that.

Comment: -Werror treats warnings as errors, i.e. they abort the compilation.

Comment: How did you not find the official documentation: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wextra ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What warnings are included in Clang's -Wall and -Wextra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904101/what-warnings-are-included-in-clangs-wall-and-wextra)

Comment: @bolov: this is Stack Overflow, **The** Internet Source For Manual Searches :-/

Comment: I did find the official document, but did not realize what it meant. Now I get it with the help of comments and the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @bolov: What use is that documentation? It says “Some of the diagnostics controlled by this flag are enabled by default.” “Some”? What use is “some”? It tells us nothing. It then tells us “Also controls…” but does not fill in the “some”. Hey, here is a program. It is fully documented to do “something.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Wextra` flag is not specific to just the clang compiler, it is documented in the [GCC Compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) as well. Basically, `-Wall` enables all (common) warning flags but this excludes many flags.

Some of these, notably `-Wempty-init-stmt`, `-Wignored-qualifiers`, `-Winitializer-overrides`, `-Wmissing-field-initializers`, `-Wmissing-method-return-type`, `-Wnull-pointer-arithmetic`, `-Wsemicolon-before-method-body`, `-Wsign-compare`, `-Wunused-parameter` are covered by `-Wextra` instead.

You can find out more about what each of these mean in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wextra).

Answer (score 2):

`-Wextra` compiler flag is not just in clang but also in **gcc**. According to the gcc docs:

> This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by `-Wall`. This option used to be called `-W`. The older name is still supported, but the newer name is more descriptive.

Source:

- [Clang docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wextra)
- [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra)

Comment: Thank you! Now I also get the meaning of -W... :)